# How WSO2 APIM Gateway Worker gets published api artifacts when distributed setup get redeployed?

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have a distributed setup of APIM in docker. Let's say we have published few API's through the publisher and then restarted the setup. Will the gateway nodes be updated with the published API artifacts or do we need to bind volumes to containers for preserving the artifacts? 
What is the process if they get auto deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic flow is when you publish an API from publisher, it will push the api artifact to the gateway manager. Based on the dep-sync scenario, gateway worker nodes will pull the api artifact.

I hope you are running separate production-ready database in docker or pointing to an external endpoint. Container restart or crash should not affect the data loss. For dep-sync you can use a SVN container or point to an external endpoint. If you use a SVN container, please mount the volumes for the container.

Basically, WSO2 server does not store anything in the file system except what you see in server folder. For the content in server folder, it is recommended to use SVN or any other mechanism to persist data of that folder.

Consider you have used SVN dep-sync for gateway cluster. Then when you respawn the APIM cluster, everything will be back to normal as gateway nodes will pull from the SVN.

Comment: We are using rsync for deployment synchronization. In that case how we should proceed?

Comment: Same concept should apply here as well. Use a volume mount for the gateway-manager node.